# How to add toolbar in product compare page

Tags: magento-1.7

Product compare located here:

```
App/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Compare/Sidebar.php
```

I have added the following code:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_Sidebar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_Abstract{
    ...
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', microtime())
            ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', microtime());
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getProductCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
}
```

My template should be like this:

```
<!-- top pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($_collection->getSize()): ?>   
 ...
<?php foreach ($_collection as $_item): ?>      
　　 ...
　　<?php endforeach; ?>
　　
<?php endif ?>
<!-- bottom pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
```

I’m added code not working in Sidebar.php. Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question...here is how you can make it show:
Replace in the block this:

```
->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
```

with this

```
->setCollection($this->getItems());
```

and remove this line:

```
$this->getProductCollection()->load()
```

IN the template file

```
<?php if($_collection->getSize()): ?>
```

showld be

```
<?php if($_helper->getItemCount() > 0): ?>
```

This should show the toolbar. I tested it on the default theme.
but why would you need such a toolbar on the sidebar? It looks ugly and it interferes with the product listing if you display the compare sidebar in the product listing (and I bet you do)

Comment: I have done what you said above,show the toolbar is well.But none of them seem to actually affect the sort order and pagination of the products on the page.What am I missing?

Comment: It doesn't work because the toolbar is designed to work with product collection. The compare items are part of an other type of collection. I recommend closing this question as it is an other case of 'how do I do Y because I want to achieve X'. Post an other question asking for the right thing, explaining what you want to achieve.